# If a bash command accepts a filename as the last arg, can piping be used to provide file content?

Tags: bash

Say a command takes a filename as its last argument:

```
count-words "$word" file.txt
```

Is there a way to use pipe in order to provide file content rather than writing to a temp file?

Comment: When you say provide file content do you mean to the terminal?

Comment: You could pass `/dev/stdin` as the last argument. See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092252/is-there-any-way-to-supply-stdin-out-instead-of-a-file-to-a-program-in-unix).

Comment: No, I meant use existing content in memory as content in the file.

Comment: @exbuddha Do you mean output from another command (via a pipe)? If so, that's what I'm talking about. Try `othercommand | count-words "$word" /dev/stdin`

Comment: Thank you. This works for me: `echo "$content" | count-words "$word" /dev/stdin`

Comment: @gordon your answer is in fact the right answer because it exactly fulfills my question but I accepted a more optimized answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your requirement correctly but you may
be in the situation that:

- You have a program (say "generate-words") which prints a text
  to the `stdout`.
- You also have a program "count-words" which counts a given word
  in the specified text file.
- You can combine two programs by writing the output of "generate-words"
  to a temporary file `file.txt`.
- But you want to find a solution without writing to a temporary file.

If the assumptions above are correct, please try:

```
count-words "$word" <(generate-words)
```

where `<(command)` is called `process substitution` and you can connect the
output (stdout) of the `command` to other program which requires filename
as an input.

Comment: This also works: `count-words "$word" <(echo "$content")` and I believe it is the optimal solution, compared with the other method mentioned by @Gordon in question comments, since it doesn't involve piping.

Answer (score 2):

Each argument, regardless of position, is a character string which the program handles itself after `bash` executes it. `bash` can't intervene in that.

Individual programs may provide an option to read from standard input, or do so by default, but if the program doesn't do that you need to point it at a file on the file system.

Answer (score 1):

Many programs will accept a single hyphen (`-`) as an instruction to use standard input. Consider, given how you're invoking your example command, the following:

```
cat file.txt | grep -Fow "$word" - | wc -l
```

This counts instances of `$word` in the given file. The `-F` option speeds up the search by disabling regular expressions (so `.` actually means `.`), `-o` sets the output to show just the matches (one per line), and the `-w` option requires a word boundary on both sides of the word (so `foo` will *not* match `food`; remove this flag to change that). `wc -l` will give you the count of the lines outputted by `grep`, which is the number of instances of `$word`. (I didn't use `grep -c` because that counts the lines with matches, which means `foo bar foo baz` on a line would be counted just once.)

---

If `count-words` is your script, consider one of these options:

```
# imply standard input when given insufficient arguments
# or when the only argument is a hyphen
# (requires you to `shift` your options and the query term)
if [ "$#" = "0" ] || [ "$*" = "-" ]; then
  set -- /dev/stdin
fi

# convert hyphen(s) to /dev/stdin within the argument list
FIRST=1
for OPT in "$@"; do
  if [ "$FIRST" = 1 ]; then
    unset FIRST
    set --
  fi
  if [ "$OPT" = "-" ]; then
    OPT="/dev/stdin"
  fi
  set -- "$@" "$OPT"
done
```

This will let you run as any of

- `count-words "$word" < file.txt`
- `get-input | count-words "$word"`
- `get-input | count-words "$word" -`
- `get-input | count-words "$word" /dev/stdin`
- `echo "$(get-input)" | count-words "$word"`
- `count-words "$word" <<<"list of words as if echoed"`
- `count-words "$word" <(get-input)`

The last three are bashisms and will not work in [`dash`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) or other simpler `/bin/sh` programs. The very last command tells `count-words` to use [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) to supply a named pipe as a temporary filehandle that stores the output of `get-input`.

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon Davisson mentioned in the comment, you could use the special file `/dev/stdin` which represents standard input.

```sh
some-command | count-words "$word" /dev/stdin
```